# Why flashdata is not working in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am using CI3 and tried to use flash data. In my controller, I set my flash data but its not showing in my controller. Here is my code in controller

```
public function add()
{
    $baseUrl=base_url();        
    $data=$this->input->post();


    $currency = new entities\AppCurrency();
    $currency->setCurrencyName($currencyName);


    try {
        $this->em->persist($currency);
        $this->em->flush();


        $this->session->set_flashdata("msg","1 Record Deleted");

        redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);


    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        $error_msg = $ex->getMessage();
    }

}
```

In view, I tried to access that flash data as follows,

```
$msg=$this->session->flashdata("msg");
echo $msg;
print_r($msg);

if(trim($msg)!=""){
  echo"
    <div class='alert alert-success'>
    ".str_replace("~","<br />",$msg)."
    </div>
  ";
}

if(trim($msg)!="" && $msg=="error"){
  echo"
    <div class='alert alert-error'>
    Could not delete due to database error. Please try again later
    </div>
  ";
}
```

Any help would be appriciated. Thanks

Comment: in which method you u r accessing the flash message msg, is it add()

Comment: @surma did u loaded session?

Comment: Edit your question with the config session info.

Comment: in config, I loaded session like this, $autoload['libraries'] = array('doctrine', 'session');

Comment: Have you check your code reach inside the try??

Comment: yes, I checked it and it reached inside the try

Answer (score 0):

Since Flash data is a function, if the variable you're looking for doesn't exist it returns false or returns what's you've stored in it.

Here's how I do it. Saves a tremendous amount of trimming and checking possibilities. You can, of course, name the flashdata fields whatever you wish, I stick basically to bootstrap naming when working with it.

#### Controller

```
$this->session->set_flashdata("success","1 Record Deleted");
$this->session->set_flashdata("error","1 Record Deleted");
$this->session->set_flashdata("info","1 Record Deleted");
$this->session->set_flashdata("warning","1 Record Deleted");
```

#### View File

```
   <?php if ($this->session->flashdata()): ?>

       <div class="flashData">

        <?php if($this->session->flashdata('success')): ?>
           <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('success') ?>
           </div>
        <?php endif ?>

        <?php if($this->session->flashdata('error')): ?>
           <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('error') ?>
           </div>
        <?php endif ?>

        <?php if($this->session->flashdata('info')): ?>
           <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
                <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('info') ?>
           </div>
        <?php endif ?>

        <?php if($this->session->flashdata('warning')): ?>
            <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
                <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('warning') ?>
            </div>
        <?php endif ?>
        </div>
      <?php endif ?>
```

A few 'gotchas' with sessions

Make sure you're either autoloading sessions or loading sessions in your controller.

Second, Make sure your `application/config/config.php` is properly configured [See CI Sessions](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html?#session-preferences)

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = APPPATH . '/cache/sessions/';  //<- must be read/write directory for files.
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```